# Enable cache Google PageSpeed

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser-cache, pagespeed, mod-expires

I trying to optimize a site and PageSpeed Insights by Google told me that I need to enable cache. So I add to my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7 day"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
BrowserMatch "MSIE" force-no-vary
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" force-no-vary
</IfModule>
```

But it didn't help, I checked phpinfo() Loaded Modules:

```
core itk http_core mod_so mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_default util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap mod_include mod_log_config mod_logio mod_env mod_ext_filter mod_mime_magic mod_expires mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_dav mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_dav_fs mod_vhost_alias mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias mod_substitute mod_rewrite mod_proxy mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_ajp mod_proxy_connect mod_cache mod_suexec mod_disk_cache mod_cgi mod_version mod_php5 mod_ispmgr
```

Everything is OK, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing the keyword `plus` in a number of your `Expires` directives which might be causing a problem.

Comment: Fixed it, but no difference

Answer (score 0):

Must try following code for the browser cache:

```
# Add Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<Filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
</Filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

It's working for me.

Other references:

1. https://dzone.com/articles/steps-improve-your-pagespeed-insight-score
2. http://www.quickregisterseo.com/improve-google-page-speed-score-wordpress-without-plugins/

Current score of my site is:
Desktop: 91
Mobile: 83